# web notification ( javascript )

Tags: javascript, push-notification, notifications, cross-browser

Q1 : How to stop Interval 
`let intervalId = setInterval(function(){
                    document.title = document.title == msg ? oldTitle : msg}, 1000);`

and and back to origin tab title ?
I try

`if (window.focus()) { clearInterval(intervalId); }`
but this is not working?

Q2 : How to focus on specific tab in the window, what I can use in addition to `window.focus()`

Q3 : Open link in new window or focus to it if already open
note : `window.open('').focus()`
always open new tab even if there is already open one

Please advice and thank you very much in advance

Comment: Your questions are quite unclear. Can you provide some context on what you are trying to do with these?

Comment: msg ? oldTitle : msg, is either falsy or oldTitle...

Comment: And no, you cannot force the user to go back to your site, thats the users decision. Have a look at service workers for the notification part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I assume you want to switch different title back and forth when the user is not in the window, and then set to the original window when the user comes back.

For Q1, I think you should listen to blur and focus event to achieve the functionality.

```js
let intervalId = null;
let original = 'original title';
let newMsg = 'new message';
// clear the timer when the user comes back
window.addEventListener('focus', function() {
  clearInterval(intervalId);
}, false);

// set the timer when the user goes away
window.addEventListener('blur', function() {
  intervalId = setInterval(function() {
    document.title = document.title === original ? newMsg : original;
  }, 1000)
}, false);
```

`

For Q2, quote from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/focus)

> It may fail due to user settings and the window isn't guaranteed to be frontmost before this method returns.

For Q3, window.open() also accepts a `windowName` parameter, when you open the window you should give the same window name to the `open()` method, so when the same window was open, it can be focused.

```
window.open('url','windowName').focus()
```

Here is an example:

```
window.open('https://www.google.com', 'google-window').focus()
```

Comment: Thank you
Q1 work correctly

Q2: I'm not understand this quote, please can you clarify it

Q3 : I try it but something missing please can you give an example

Comment: Q2: It means you cannot forcing a user to focus on specific tab, it's up to the browser's behavior or user's settings.

Comment: Thank you this is more clear, please what about question 3 please if you can provide an example?

Comment: example added at the end

Comment: this is work perfectly in case open then focus 
but this solution not work to focus if not open,  please advice